# How to speed up the mobile version of a Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, performance, mobile, mobile-safari, pagespeed

I have a Wordpress website that has a photo slider on the homepage. Also, my blog page loads extremely slow both on desktop and mobile. Can someone please help me with this? https://clfapartments.com
https://clfapartments.com/blog

Comment: Compress your images and reduce the size to the size of your slider - https://clfapartments.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Cass-Lake-Front-Apartments-Keego-Harbor-MI.jpg this is 2.5MB - could probably be < 200kb

Answer (score 0):

If most of the content is static, use a caching plugin. There are numerous free ones plus some premium versions. WpRocket for example allows a dedicated mobile cache.

Another option is a content delivery network if you are willing to pay for one.

Comment: I have a picture slider on the homepage

Comment: A CDN and Caching plugin will work and improve speed of the slider also.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to doing your mobile speed optimization you have to use child of your theme and do cache from ht access or use any plugin for that and optimize CSS or using bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

depend on your php server you can use wprocket or litespeed plugins.
if your php server is Apache, use wprocket plugin
if else your ph server is litespeed, I recommend strongly use litespeed plugin.
by the way if you just want speed up your mobile version of your site and css or javascript are not matter , you can use AMP plugin for your wordpress website.